# How to integrate Flash into Firefox?

Tags: html, flash, firefox

I want to embed a flash animation into my standard updated Firefox.
(Firefox has flash installed and works with flash sites)

I use that : (it works on chrome and IE), but gives an EMPTY place in Firefox

```
<object id="videoPlayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="400px">
    <param name="movie" value=swf/player.swf />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
</object>
```

I also tried with:

```
<embed id="videoPlayer" src="swf/player.swf" width="100%" height="400px"/>
```

Same result:
I don't want to use complex JS scripts to activate Flash.

Comment: Try using a full URL path. Example would be... `src="http://www.website.com/swf/player.swf" `

Comment: Your embed code was more on the right track just need to change out a few things, see answer below. Objects are much more simplified these days.

Answer (score 0):

Object tags have changed slightly. This should work in IE, Chrome and Firefox. It works for me.

```
<object data="swf/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="400"></object>
```